# Stuck trying to append an element to an vector within a matrix

Tags: swift, matrix, vector

Hopefully I explain this properly.

So I have an instance of an empty matrix that can hold vectors of Doubles

```
var matrix:[[Double]] = [[Double]]()
```

I'm trying to append an element to what will be the first vector within the matrix, but because the matrix is empty I can't reference the vector to append to it.

For example, I want to append 1.0 to the first vector in the matrix with

```
matrix[0].append(1.0)
```

But because `matrix[0]` doesn't actually exist yet I can't append to it.

Is there a way to create a new vector within the matrix if it doesn't exist to then append to, and from then on just append to the existing vector.

For context:

After adding 1.0 to position 0,0 in the matrix, I will then need to add another number to 1,0 in the matrix. Then 2,0... 3,0... 4,0 etc.

Then later I'll need to start from the top and add a number to 0,1... then 1,1... 2,1... 3,1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of rows in the matrix size up-front, you can initialize the matrix right from the start with empty rows:

```swift
var matrix: [[Double]] = .init(repeating: [], count: numberOfRows)
```

You can then append to any row:

```swift
matrix[someValidIndex].append(someDouble)
```

Now, if you also know the number of columns, you can also initialize the whole matrix with a default value, e.g. 0.0, this will give you a small performance boost, as you'll avoid extra memory allocations when appending:

```swift
var matrix: [[Double]] = .init(repeating: .init(repeating: 0.0, count: numberOfColummns), count: numberOfRows)
```

, and in this case you can simply assign to the desired location:

```swift
matrix[i][j] = someValue
```